# How to get all possible combinations of three lists

Tags: python, combinations

I have three lists:

```
list_a=[1,2]
list_b=[3,4]
list_c=[5,6]
```

Now i'm looking for a solution in python  by using a loop where a new list iterates through all
possible combinations of these three lists (the order is not important):

```
new_list = list_a # -> [1,2]
new_list = list_b # -> [3,4]
new_list = list_c # -> [5,6]
new_list = list_a + list_b # -> [1,2,3,4]
new_list = list_b + list_c # -> [3,4,5,6]
new_list = list_a + list_c # -> [1,2,5,6]
new_list = List_a + list_b + list_c # -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I found some similar posts with "itertools" or nested loops, but nothing exactly like this...

Comment: Why isn't the last result `[1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,1,2]`?

Comment: @Barmar maybe distinct?

Comment: Is the order important? If not, use `set(list_a).union(list_b).union(list_c)`

Comment: I'm confused as to why the sixth entry is c + a and not a + c. Seems to be the odd one out if it's combinations in order.

Comment: So do you want the output to be [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], [5,6,1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]?

Comment: If ordering is not matter you can convert 3 lists to sets and use union method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

out = [list(chain.from_iterable(l)) 
          for i in range(3) 
          for l in combinations([list_a, list_b, list_c], i+1)]

# Output
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```